# get request to a website returns error

Tags: java, sockets, get-request

I was trying to send a get request to a website but always return error 400 bad request. I'm wondering if my get request is wrong or not. Here it is;

```
socketOut.println("GET " + req.url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
socketOut.flush();
```

I can do it by using URLConnection but as a second way I'm using socket. So I'm sending this request and readinng bytes. I checked what it returns to me from website and of course it returns bad request error page. Any suggestion? By the way req.url returns a url not something like /asd.html but this www.stackoverflow.com/asd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println` may use `\n` as new line instead of `\r\n` which might be required. Try using `\r\n` directly.

HTTP 1.1 requires `Host` header. Try:

```
socketOut.print("GET " + req.url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
```

or:

```
socketOut.print("GET " + req.url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
socketOut.print("Host: " + req.host + "\r\n");
socketOut.print("\r\n");
```